# Ionic where to define function for button defined in app.html

Tags: angular, ionic-framework, side-menu

I have defined my Ionic side menu in `app.html`:

```
<ion-menu [content]="content" side="left">
  <ion-header>
    <ion-toolbar>
        <ion-title>Menu</ion-title>
    </ion-toolbar>
  </ion-header>

  <ion-content>
    <ion-list>
        <button  menuClose ion-item (click)="openProfilePage()">Start today's quiz</button>
    </ion-list>
  </ion-content>

</ion-menu>
```

Where  can I define the function `openProfilePage` function. I mean in which file?

Comment: In app.component.ts

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should define your function inside app.component.ts file.

```
public openProfilePage() {
    // Code here
}
```

Comment: I'm getting `StaticInjectorError(AppModule)[Nav -> NavController]: 
  StaticInjectorError(Platform: core)[Nav -> NavController]: 
    NullInjectorError: No provider for NavController!`

Comment: Because I am doing `this.navCtrl.push(ProfilePage);`

Comment: OK, I solved this by using `import {App} from 'ionic-angular';`